# `du` takes current directory when using in pipe with find

Tags: bash, shell

I'm using a script in which I look for a file in a directory (and all of its  subdirectories) and print the file + file's size.

It is like this :

```
find $folder -name $file | du --apparent-size
```

(with the inputs `$folder=folder_1` and `$file=f1`
The problem is that my output is

```
4   ./folder_1/f1
8   ./folder_1
13  .
```

Whereas the output of `find $folder -name $file` is only

```
folder_1/f1/file1
folder_1/file1
```

Why does it take my current directory, even if there is no file matching my search ?

Comment: Use the `prune` switch, for example if you want to exclude the `abc` directory just add a `-path ./abc -prune -o` to your find command

Comment: In my case, `file1` is not in my current directory. But what if it'd be ? I cannod exclude that directory.

Comment: Sorry took your question wrong. I think @vdavid has given the solution

Comment: As to what was your issue: `du` does not read from pipe. So your command was pretty much equivalent to only calling `du --apparent-size`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the `-exec` option:

```
find "$folder" -name "$file" -exec du --apparent-size '{}' \;
```